# How To "Mask" A Sub-Domain With Real Domain?

Tags: dns

I don't know to much about masking, but this is my problem.

I used a web builder to make a website, and they gave me a sub-domain. atm i can't buy premium so i don't have access for changing the sub-domain to the real domain.

The domain is brought on "NameCheap.com", and i was wondering if there is a way to make it so when someone types in "Domain.com" it shows the website attached to the sub domain "Domain.sub.com", but i don't want the url to show the old sub domain? and when they go on a page i want it to say "Domain.com/page" not "domain.sub.com/page". Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CNAME records to accomplish this.
CNAME record ROOT (.) and www. to point to subdomain.domain.com.

If subdomain.domain.com don't have scripts that force a redirect to their address you should be in the clear, if not you may have to fork over some dough!

The above is under the proviso you have a DNS service available for you to whack in some records. Most providers do but it may be extra, simply owning the domain isn't enough to make it work.